# `setState` doesn't update array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that renders an array with `.map()` and a button that `setState` the shuffled version of it.

I'm trying to have it update every time I click that button but it doesn't.

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [random, setRandom] = useState(students);

  function randomize() {
    const shuffle = students.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
    setRandom(shuffle);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <main className="container mx-auto flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center p-4">
        <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold">This week&apos;s seat</h1>

        <button onClick={randomize}>Shuffle</button>

        {/* Seatings */}
        <div className="seatbox">
          {random.map((student) => (
            <Seat key={student}>{student}</Seat>
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};
```

I tried to log the `random` state, it got updated it just doesn't get rendered probably.

The `Seat` component is made with styled-components and the `students` array is an array of strings with the students name like this

```
const students = [
  "Joe",
  "Jason"
]
```

Comment: sort mutates the array in place .... make a copy before sorting - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606342/react-doesnt-rerender-on-state-update/73606436#73606436)

Comment: `const shuffle = [ ...students ].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sorts the array:

```
const shuffle = students.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
```

*But...* it sorts the array *in place* and returns a reference to that *same array*.  Since the reference equality hasn't changed (an array is a kind of object after all), React has no way to know that the state has been updated.  It doesn't do any kind of deep compare, just an equality comparison for whatever is sent to it.

If you duplicate the array just before sorting (so as to not mutate it), the newly sorted array will be a new object reference and won't be "equal" to the previous state:

```
const shuffle = [...students].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
```